# How to fix commitlint error404?

Tags: npm, husky, commitlint

I'm trying to configure my app and it's my first time installing commitlint + husky. Commitlint was working fine untill I installed Husky. Now i'm stuck with this error when i'm trying to **commit -m** to my repository.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/comitlint - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'comitlint@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xflame/.npm/_logs/2022-04-03T17_02_18_645Z-debug-0.log
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: ` 'comitlint@latest' is not in this registry.` - Looks like a typo for me, I guess this should be `commitlint`

Comment: @ChristianHeld wow, that was easy, you really helped me. I just had to change npx comitlint --edit to npx commitlint --edit in husky folder. Now evertyhing works fine. Little things makes big problems, thank you!